# If statement doesn't word as planned

Tags: java

could you have a look at my code and tell me why it doesn't work as planned

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char card1 = ' ';
char card2 = ' ';
int count = 0;
int globalCount = 0;
do {
    globalCount++;
    card1 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    card2 = sc.next().charAt(0);
    if ((card1 >= 2 && card1 <= 9 || card1 == 'T' || card1 == 'J' || card1 == 'Q' || card1 == 'K' || card1 == 'A') && (card2 >= 2 && card2 <= 9 || card2 == 'T' || card2 == 'J' || card2 == 'Q' || card2 == 'K' || card2 == 'A')){
        if (card1 == 'A' || card1 == 'K' && card2 == 'A' || card2 == 'K') {
            count++;
        }else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("Invalid cards given!");

    }
}while (count < 3);
System.out.println("Number of tries: " + globalCount);
```

If I input for `card1` an number I always get an `Invalid cards given` even though I think in my if statement I specified that it could take a number as well? Also a little pointer as if I can avoid the repetition of those `card1 == 'T'` and so on?

Comment: Also this is the task -- "Write a program that reads two characters separated by space – each one - the
strength of a card. Possible inputs are from 2..9 or T, J, Q, K, A. If the input is invalid
the program must output the following : “Invalid cards given!”. The inputs are infinite.
The program must stop when 3 consecutive pairs of ace(A) and king(K) are given. Finally,
the program must ouput the number of tries."

Comment: `2` is not the same as `'2'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char card1 = ' ';
char card2 = ' ';
int count = 0;
int globalCount = 0;
do {
    globalCount++;
    card1 = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
    card2 = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (((card1 - '0' >= 2 && card1  - '0' <= 9) || card1 == 'T' || card1 == 'J' || card1 == 'Q' || card1 == 'K' || card1 == 'A') && ((card2 - '0' >= 2 && card2 - '0' <= 9) || card2 == 'T' || card2 == 'J' || card2 == 'Q' || card2 == 'K' || card2 == 'A')){
        if (card1 == 'A' || card1 == 'K' && card2 == 'A' || card2 == 'K') {
            count++;
        }else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("Invalid cards given!");

    }
}while (count < 3);
System.out.println("Number of tries: " + globalCount);
```

This comparison

```
card1 >= 2
```

compares the ascii code of the char entered with 2 and not the numeric representation of card1.  
So to get this numeric representation you have to subtract the ascii code of `'0'`.  
By subtracting `card1-'0'` you get the number you entered as opposed to the ascii code you get by only card1, because this what a char is really: an ASCII code from 0 to 255.

Comment: Great, it works now, thanks, but can you explain to me what does this do exactly?

Comment: It isn't really necessary to subtract `'0'` from it. `card1 >= '2' && card1 <= '9'` will do the same.

Comment: @Ivar it isn't really necessary to compare to `'2'` because you can subtract `'0'`

Comment: @Ivar are you serious? Subtracting `'0'` from `'5'` gives you the number 5. Can't you get it?

Comment: @Ivar No you don't get it: OP wants the number to be between 2 and 9, so I transform `'5'` to `5` by subtracting `'0'`. If I subtracted `'a'` from it I would not get a number from 0 to 9.

Comment: No, I _do_ get it. You are just completely missing my point. `card1 - '0' >= 2 && card1  - '0' <= 9` will always have the same output as `card1 >= '2' && card1 <= '9'`. The difference is that one does an extra calculation that is not necessary for the comparison, nor for code readability.

Comment: @Ivar maybe now you get it, but your previous comments about why I subract `'0'` as it would be the same to subract `'^'` proved that you did not get it.  Now I believe this is enough. Don't misuse the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

Your current condition for `card1` and `card2`

```
(card1 >= 2 && card1 <= 9 || card1 == 'T' || ...
```

won't be true for number cards. `char` type stores the two-byte Unicode value. To check if this value is between character `2` and `9` you have to express the constants in the same way you are comparing symbol cards:

```
(card1 >= '2' && card1 <= '9' || card1 == 'T' ||  ...
```

You can do avoid repeating code by defining all allowed values as `String` and using `String.indexOf()`. Your check would be converted to:

```
"23456789TJQKA".indexOf(char1) >= 0
```